# number of characters in the string

Tags: c++, string

I am new to c++ and I am trying to figure out how to set an int variable place to the number of characters in the string variable name using the length() function.

Would it be something like this?

```
place.length() = length(name);
```

Comment: what are the types of `place` and `name`?

Comment: Place is an int name is a string.

Comment: @SilverNightFall: Is that a `std::string` or a `char*` or a `char[]`? There are many things in C++ that could be called a "string"; you have to be more specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question, its something like:

```
int place = name.size();
```

Remember that the `string::size()` member function returns a `size_t`, so you may want to consider storing the size in a `size_t` or at least an `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't have a `std::length(const C&)` function.

Are you looking for non-static member function `std::string::size_type std::string::size() const`?